# Access token validation

Tags: security, facebook-graph-api, web-applications, access-token, facebook-access-token

In my application I want to implement facebook graph like security.So Access tokens are created at server side and then they are send to client at the time of login.After that when client make request then the access tokens are appended at the request header.

But at server side how can I validate that the request is from valid user.

Scenario:-
I mean it can also happen that when client send request, some middle party can copy the whole request and then the middle party can send that request to server and server will send the response.This scenario I want to deal.
Please provide some suggestion on how can I verify that request is form valid user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement SSL/[TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) to allow access to your application over [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS).

This will prevent [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) being constructed by a [Man-In-The-Middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) or [eavesdropper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eavesdropping).

Comment: That's a prevention.But is there any way to validate request? Also I found term machineid,while searching for it. Can I unqily identify client by machine id or ip?

Comment: Validate the access token is correct. If you properly transport it over HTTPS only then it can't be grabbed by an attacker.